# Get child key of json in expressjs and ejs

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm using expressjs, mongodb and ejs in this project. Once I populate the dbs, the data looks like this:

```
{
  _id: 5645646464,
  price: 15000,
  sellerId: {
    _id: 3543453242,
    Name: 'MrJohn'
  },
  name: 'House of MrJohn',
  category: '1'
}
```

Now in my html using EJS I want to print  "MrJohn" in my `seller` column, I have tried this:

```
<%=data[i].sellerId.Name%>
```

but it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the relevant code which does the populate?

Comment: Close this question , i resolved this ,thanks.

Comment: You can delete if you so wish